# How to add HTTP Status code and status text in to response with ellipsesynergie/api-response In Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-status-code-301, laravel-response

We will need to add status code in to the response.

Like

```
public function withArray(array $array, array $headers = array()) {
if ($this->statusCode == '200') {
$array = array('code' => $this->statusCode , 'success' => TRUE) + $array;
} else {
$array = array('code' => $this->statusCode, 'success' => FALSE) + $array;
}
return response()->json($array, $this->statusCode, $headers);
}
```

For now, we had modified library code on `"ellipsesynergie/api-response/src/Laravel/Response.php"`.

But I feel. Its not good way.

Could you please suggest me how can i add this to all response without change library code ?

Or Is there any way to add the status code from controller for final response.

Actually, we will need final response like "http://screencast.com/t/nmWF7PYU".

Please help us on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just make your own `Response` class wich extends `EllipseSynergie\ApiResponse\Laravel\Response`. Let's call it `App\ApiResponse\MyResponse`

Overwrite all methods in `EllipseSynergie\ApiResponse\Laravel\Response` with your own.
For example:

```
public function withArray(array $array, array $headers = array())
{
    $array['code'] = $this->statusCode;
    $array['success'] = true;

    return parent::withArray($array, $headers);
}
```

Then in your `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` register you class something like:

```
$myResponse = new \App\ApiResponse\MyResponse(new \League\Fractal\Manager());    
$this->app->instance('EllipseSynergie\ApiResponse\Contracts\Response', $myResponse);
```